# About WSO2 Throttling policies

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, throttling

I was wondering about the performance of WSO2 throttling. Whilst checking it out, I did the following :

- I created a new subscription tier (say Tier1)
- I set a limit of 10 requests per hour on it
- I created another subscription tier (say Tier2)
- I set a limit of 20 requests per hour on it
- I allowed my API to use those tiers and created a test application to use the API with Tier1
- Using the API console, I started sending requests to my API
- After the 10 calls(though it exceeded 10), I unsubscribed the test application and subscribed to the same API using the same application using Tier2
- It took around 15 mins for the throttler to unlock. Which brings me to my first concern ...

> **How long does it take for a change in tier subscription to reflect on the same application????**

In relation to the excess calls going through, I also set up tiers with limits on a per minute basis. Once again, I noticed excess calls going through.
What I also noticed was that this excess was in the initial number of calls and the throttling worked normally after those initial excess calls.
Which leads to my next ...

> **How long does it take for a newly set up tier to throttle properly? In the per-minute basis, I assume that some calls carry over to the next minute. Am I right in assuming that?**

Any help in understanding this would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What's the API Manager version that you are using?

Comment: API Manager v2.0.0